# How to check multiple conditions in an IF statement with dialog confirms

Tags: jquery

I am trying to work out if a user has clicked `OK` or `Cancel` in a Javascript alert box, depending on which button was clicked on the page. I previously had two submit buttons on a page which were `Save` and `Send`. But since then I've added a `Create` submit button and can't seem to fit it into my code.

Here is my code which works when there is only a `Save` and `Send` submit button on the page:

```
$("#form").on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
    if (!$("#form").valid() 
|| !($(this).is('#Save') ? confirmAction('SaveRecord') : confirmAction('SendRecord'))) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    } 
    else { 
      //continue to process the form 
    }
});
```

What's happening is that when the user clicks on a submit button, its checking that the form is valid and that if the user clicked `Save` then to show and check they clicked OK on the `SaveRecord` confirmAction() alert box. Or if they didn't click on `Save` then it assumes they clicked on `Send` and shows and checks that the user confirmed the `SendRecord` confirmAction() alert box.

I now want to add a `Create` button to the page. When this button is clicked it should show and check that the user clicked OK on the `CreateRecord` confirmAction() alert box.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$("#form").on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
    if (!$("#form").valid() 
|| !($(this).is('#Create') confirmAction('CreateRecord')) //this doesn't work!! 
|| !($(this).is('#Save') ? confirmAction('SaveRecord') : confirmAction('SendRecord'))) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    } 
    else { 
      //continue to process the form 
    }
});
```

How can I ensure that when `Create` is clicked it will only continue if the user confirmed that action? I would prefer not to use the `?` operator for OR and have each button on its own line. Something like this:

```
if (!$("#form").valid() 
    || !($(this).is('#Create') confirmAction('CreateRecord'))
    || !($(this).is('#Save') confirmAction('SaveRecord')) 
    || !($(this).is('#Send') confirmAction('SendRecord'))) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
```

How could I do it?

Comment: Can you please provide us with a codepen version of what you're doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo up there (missing `?` after the `is ('#Create')` part, and then another `:` and follow-up would be needed. But even with all those fixes, it's going to be quite a mess - not least with all the negation going on.

I'd suggest writing it a bit more verbosely, but much more clearly, as:

```
var valid = $("#form").valid();
var clk = $(this);

if (valid)
{
  if      (clk.is('#Create'))
    valid = confirmAction('CreateRecord');
  else if (clk.is('#Save'))
    valid = confirmAction('SaveRecord');
  else    // must be #Send
    valid = confirmAction('SendRecord');
}

if (! valid)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
} 
else { 
  //continue to process the form 
}
```

Comment: This is great, but don't you need opening and closing `{` for the nested `if` statements?

Comment: The only nesting is within `if (valid)`. The `if` ... `else if` ... `else` conditions aren't nested.

Comment: my editor kept saying "expected { but instead saw valid" as an error. So i wasn't sure and went ahead and added them like this: `if (valid) { if (clk.is("#Create")) { valid = confirmAction('CreateRecord'); }`

Comment: Then there's something else up in your JS. Nothing in this example would cause that error on its own.

Comment: I think its Dreamweaver's built-in validator thats not correct. The code itself runs perfectly fine with no errors in Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a quick fiddle for what I think you are asking for.  https://jsfiddle.net/7pfzgmr2/

Instead of the inline if statement:

```
if (!$("#form").valid() 
    || !($(this).is('#Create') confirmAction('CreateRecord'))
    || !($(this).is('#Save') confirmAction('SaveRecord')) 
    || !($(this).is('#Send') confirmAction('SendRecord'))) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
```

I used 3 if statements, all based on the last, so if the form isn't valid, it doesn't care about which button you clicked.

```
var doNotSend = !$("#form").valid();
if (!doNotSend && $t.is("#create")) 
    doNotSend = !confirm("Create Record?");
if (!doNotSend && $t.is("#save")) 
    doNotSend = !confirm("Save Record?");
if (!doNotSend && $t.is("#send")) 
    doNotSend = !confirm("Send Record?");
```

You also mentioned that you were using an alert box.  In my example above, you can see I just use confirm, which does the same thing you mention your `confirmAction` method does.